# Do this if all checkboxes are checked or this if not (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

i'm trying to do following:

- user can continue to next step only if all checkboxes are checked
- in other case if user click on button, it should popup alert message for example

I can't figure out the second part if checkboxes are not all checked. Here is my code:

```
$("input[type='checkbox'].checkbox").change(function(){
    var a = $("input[type='checkbox'].checkbox");
    if (a.length == a.filter(":checked").length){
        $('.button').on('click',function(){
            // do something, no issue here
        });
    } else {
        // do something else, can't figure this out
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you asking how to popup an alert message?

Comment: A click handler inside a change handler will cause issues

Comment: else { alert('please select all check boxes'); }

Is that all you are looking for?

Comment: BTW: Wouldn't it be simpler to check that the number of unchecked boxes>0 rather than test the number of checked boxes against the total boxes?

Comment: No sir, i'm asking how write another "if" when some checkbox is not checked, so clicking on button will do other thing than when all checkboxes are checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the boxes are checked inside the click handler, don't attach the click handler based on checked boxes :

```
$('.button').on('click',function(){
    var boxes = $('.checkbox[type="checkbox"]');
    if ( boxes.length === boxes.filter(':checked').length ) {
         // all checked
    }else{
         // not all checked
    }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what i need. I'm a bit smarter by now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<input type='checkbox' id="1" />
<br />
<input type='checkbox' id="2" />
<br />
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    // GET ALL TOTAL CHECKED CHECKBOXES
    var total_checked = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

    // TOTAL CHECK BOXES
    var total_boxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]').length

    if(total_checked === total_boxes) {
           alert('Checked All');
    } else {
         alert('Please select all check boxes'); return false;
    }

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A9MBS/1/

**Suggestion:** Once user clicks on 1 particular check box, dynamically select all

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {

    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    }

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A9MBS/2/

Answer (score 1):

You should check if all the checkboxes are checked when the button is clicked

```
$('.button').on('click',function(){
  var a = $("input[type='checkbox'].checkbox");
  if(a.length == a.filter(":checked").length){
    // do something, no issue here
  }
  else {
    // do alert thingy
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this
the html

```
<input type='checkbox' name="chkb" />
<input type='checkbox' name="chkb" />
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

the script code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').on('click',function(){
        if($('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').length>0)
            alert("please select all checkboxes");
    });
});
```

this code checks if all checkboxes are not selected in a single selector